# XCode 6.1.1 Mac App link error ScalableUserInterface.framework

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6.1.1

I am getting a link error building a Mac App that used to build fine.

```
ld: file not found: /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ScalableUserInterface.framework/Versions/A/ScalableUserInterface for architecture x86_64
```

I dont deliberately use or reference ScalableUserInterface.framework and XCode is quite correct that in QuartzCore.framework I dont have ScalableUserInterface.framework (only CoreImage)

I'm not sure whether this is something referenced by other system frameworks which I ought to have (its possible that this started happening after a laptop death needing a clean install of everything) so I need to get it from somewhere (reinstall XCode?), or whether it is something that I have accidentally started to reference (by checking summat in a .xib - I have autolayout off in all .xibs)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused simply by the file being missing. MacOSX 10.9 had been clean installed by the Apple Store after a motherboard replacement. Looked on another Mac and the framework was where XCode was looking for it, copied it across and hey presto...
I wonder what other system files are missing...